# Falha ao fazer a gravação dos campos do utilizador no editor de vendas

Tags: c#

Quando o artigo é identificado ele faz todas as alterações abaixo que ele têm para fazer. Quando gravo o *Documento de Venda* ele não grava corretamente as alteração no documento, quando carrego o documento posteriormente gravado alguns campos continuam vazios ou incompletos.

- **CDU_Lote** e **CDU_Variedade** abaixo estão como `nvarchar` e também estão presentes no *LinhasDoc*.
- **CDU_Caixas** é gravado de maneira correta (`int`)
- **CDU_Lote** só grava 10 caracteres (`nvarchar 20`)
- **CDU_Variedade** não grava de todo e fica dentro da base de dados como `null` (`nvarchar 50`)
- A Descrição é corretamente gravada

Quando o artigo é identificado:
[image: Artigo é identificado]

Quando o documento gravado é carregado:
[image: Documento gravado é carregado]

Código

```cs
public override void ArtigoIdentificado(string Artigo, int NumLinha, ref bool Cancel, ExtensibilityEventArgs e)
{
    base.ArtigoIdentificado(Artigo, NumLinha, ref Cancel, e); 
    DocumentoVenda.Linhas.GetEdita(NumLinha).CamposUtil["CDU_Caixas"].Valor = 30;
    DocumentoVenda.Linhas.GetEdita(NumLinha).CamposUtil["CDU_Lote"].Valor = "0123456789A";
    DocumentoVenda.Linhas.GetEdita(NumLinha).CamposUtil["CDU_Variedade"].Valor = "Nova-Vila L";
    DocumentoVenda.Linhas.GetEdita(NumLinha).Descricao = "Descr";
}
```

Comment: Olá, testei o mesmo cenário e os valores também não estão a ser gravados. Coloca um ticket para que isto seja resolvido.

Comment: Testei igualmente na V9.15 e aparentemente é bug. Contacta o produtor do software.